My car is totaled and my ex is in the car title
Me and my ex got a car together, we're both on the car title. I totaled the car out, my car insurance wants us to both sign however I asked him and he is refusing to sign what should I do?

This question is similar to: How to remove my partner's name off a car title?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

There are a lot of similar questions here. Basically, you'll need to negotiate a resolution with the coowner of the car.

You own half the car, your ex owns half the car.

my car insurance wants us to both sign however I asked him and he is
refusing to sign what should I do?

When the insurance company has determined that the repairs are too expensive compared to the value of the car, they give the owners a check for the value of the car.
They use the information on the car title to write the check.
Based on your question both names are on the title, and the check should have the word "and" between the names.
If everything was fair, the obvious solution would be to split the value of the check.
Of course that would leave you short if the goal was to use the funds to buy a similar replacement. If they decided years ago that the car is yours it would have been better to get that in writing. The title could even have been changed at that time.
You either have to negotiate a compromise, or get help. Is there a common friend who would be willing to talk to them.
In the United States there are small claims courts, they have limits regarding maximum value involved, but they also don't involve lawyers so that expense can be skipped. The judge will still want to know why you should get more than half.
